# reading a document and finding a specific word in that document

Tags: c, parsing, text

I have the following document:

```
WTPZ24 KNHC 032040
TCMEP4

TROPICAL STORM SIMON FORECAST/ADVISORY NUMBER   9
NWS NATIONAL HURRICANE CENTER MIAMI FL       EP192014
2100 UTC FRI OCT 03 2014

THERE ARE NO COASTAL WATCHES OR WARNINGS IN EFFECT.

TROPICAL STORM CENTER LOCATED NEAR 18.8N 110.6W AT 03/2100Z
POSITION ACCURATE WITHIN  20 NM

REPEAT...CENTER LOCATED NEAR 18.8N 110.6W AT 03/2100Z
AT 03/1800Z CENTER WAS LOCATED NEAR 18.6N 110.1W

FORECAST VALID 04/0600Z 19.2N 112.2W
MAX WIND  65 KT...GUSTS  80 KT.
64 KT... 10NE   0SE   0SW  10NW.
50 KT... 30NE  30SE  20SW  20NW.
34 KT... 50NE  50SE  40SW  40NW.

FORECAST VALID 04/1800Z 20.0N 114.3W
MAX WIND  75 KT...GUSTS  90 KT.
64 KT... 20NE  10SE  10SW  20NW.
```

and I am trying to make a program in C that will read through the file and find the word string FORECASt VALID.  Everytime a line has the words FORECAST VALID I want the program to print the line and "===>" before the line.  For the rest of the document I just want it to simply print the line.

The final output put by the program should look like this:

```
REPEAT...CENTER LOCATED NEAR 18.8N 110.6W AT 03/2100Z
AT 03/1800Z CENTER WAS LOCATED NEAR 18.6N 110.1W

===>FORECAST VALID 04/0600Z 19.2N 112.2W
MAX WIND  65 KT...GUSTS  80 KT.
64 KT... 10NE   0SE   0SW  10NW.
50 KT... 30NE  30SE  20SW  20NW.
34 KT... 50NE  50SE  40SW  40NW.

===>FORECAST VALID 04/1800Z 20.0N 114.3W
MAX WIND  75 KT...GUSTS  90 KT.
64 KT... 20NE  10SE  10SW  20NW.
```

I do have some snippets of code that print the document verbatim without the ===> but I just need help in how to isolate out FORECAST VALID from a line so as to put the ===> in those lines:

```
FILE *fr;            /* declare the file pointer */

main()
{
   int n;
   char line[800];
   char buf[255];
   fr = fopen ("wtnt23.knhc.201410141453", "rt");  /* open the file for reading */

   while(fgets(line, 800, fr) != NULL)
   {
    sscanf (line, "%s", buf);
    if (buf="FORECAST")
   {
       printf("===>%s",line);
   }
   else
   {
        printf("%s",line);
   }
   fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
} /*of main*/
```

Comment: You might find the standard C library function `strncmp()` useful for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

`if (buf="FORECAST")` is totally wrong. it is not compare and you can't copy to char array with a `=`...

You just need to do like this:

```
while(fgets(line, 800, fr) != NULL)
{
   if(0 == strncmp(line, "FORECAST VALID", strlen("FORECAST VALID")) )
   {
       printf("===>%s",line);
   }
   else
   {
        printf("%s",line);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::strings` and `iostreams` rather than char arrays and `FILE*`.

Something a bit like:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("wtnt23.knhc.201410141453");

    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // loop as long as getline() succeeds
    {
        if(line.find("FORECAST VALID") == 0) // line starts with this?
        {
             // output ===>
        }
        // output line + linefeed
    }
}
```